# conditional initialization of static arrays, using compound literals

Tags: c, c99

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define INIT_UINT32 1
#define INIT_INT32  2

#define INIT INIT_INT32

typedef union
{
  uint32_t a;
  int32_t  b;
} Foo_t;

/* Why does this compile... */
static Foo_t foo_static = INIT == INIT_INT32 ?
    (Foo_t){ .a = UINT32_MAX} : (Foo_t){ .b = INT32_MAX };

/* but this doesn't? */
static Foo_t foo_static_array[] =
{
  INIT == INIT_INT32 ? (Foo_t){ .a = UINT32_MAX} : (Foo_t){ .b = INT32_MAX }
};

int main(void)
{
}
```

When compiled, the conditional initialization of foo_static using compound literals succeeds, but the conditional initialization of foo_static_array using compound literals fails. Following are the compile errors.

```
$ gcc test.c
test.c:4:21: error: initializer element is not constant
    4 | #define INIT_INT32  2
      |                     ^
test.c:6:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘INIT_INT32’
    6 | #define INIT INIT_INT32
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
test.c:21:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘INIT’
   21 |   INIT == INIT_INT32 ? (Foo_t){ .a = UINT32_MAX} : (Foo_t){ .b = INT32_MAX }
      |   ^~~~
test.c:4:21: note: (near initialization for ‘foo_static_array[0]’)
    4 | #define INIT_INT32  2
      |                     ^
test.c:6:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘INIT_INT32’
    6 | #define INIT INIT_INT32
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
test.c:21:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘INIT’
   21 |   INIT == INIT_INT32 ? (Foo_t){ .a = UINT32_MAX} : (Foo_t){ .b = INT32_MAX }
      |   ^~~~
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Both initializers are governed by C 2018 6.7.9 4: “All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.” There is no rule in the C standard that initializers for non-arrays are done at run time.

Comment: I guess it's the idea of "compile-time constant" that's tripping me up. The value of the expression, "INIT == INIT_INT32 ? (Foo_t){ .a = UINT32_MAX} : (Foo_t){ .b = INT32_MAX }" can be computed at compile time, so why isn't it considered a "compile-time constant"?

Comment: The fact that something can be computed at compile-time does not mean the C standard requires a compiler to computed it at compile-time or that a compiler does compute it at compile time. The C standard specifies *constant expressions* in clause 6.6.

Comment: Side note: the logic in those conditional expressions seems to be reversed. When `INIT == INIT_INT32` is true I would have expected the initializer with `.b = INT32_MAX` to have been chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is providing the former initialization as an extension to the C standard. It is not providing the latter. This is a GCC choice, not mandated by the standard. With `-pedantic`, GCC complains about both.

The relevant passage in the C standard is C 2018 6.7.9 4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

This is in a Constraints section, which means a conforming compiler must diagnose it, as GCC does when `-pedantic` is used, although it still accepts the code and completes compilation. Without `-pedantic`, GCC accepts both but only diagnoses the latter.

The GCC documentation on C extensions is silent about the reason for this difference. Its [clause 6.27](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Initializers.html#Initializers) says that initializers for aggregates with automatic storage duration are not required to be constant expressions, but there is no subclause in the C extensions clause that addresses initializers for static objects.

To make your code strictly conforming, you should not use these initializers in either the non-array or the array initialization.

Comment: So, could you explain why `(Foo_t){ .a = 0}` is a constant expression, and so is `2 == 2 ? 0 : 1`, but `2 == 2 ? (Foo_t){ .a = 0} : (Foo_t){ .b = 1};` isn't?

Comment: I suggest some reference to 6.6 7 and 6.6 10 too.

Comment: Or if `(Foo_t){ .a = 0}` is *not* a constant expression, then why does GCC allow it as an initializer, even under `-pedantic`?  Are you saying that is an extension too?

Comment: @NateEldredge Because compound literals are not constant expressions, although the *address* of a compound literal with static storage duration *is* a constant expression.

Comment: @NateEldredge: In the absence of documentation, we cannot be entirely sure why GCC accepts a compound literal as a constant. In both cases, array and non-array, it is diagnosed when `-pedantic` is used. This could be either because GCC accepts a compound literal as an extension and is required to diagnose it as a constraint violation or because GCC defines a compound literal as an “other form” of constant expression per C 2018 6.6 10 (“An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.”) and chooses to diagnose it even though it is then not required.

Comment: @IanAbbott: `(Foo_t){ .a = 0}` is not the address of a compound literal and is not converted to the address of a compound literal.

Comment: But `Foo_t static_foo = (Foo_t){.a = 0};` is not diagnosed even with `-pedantic`: https://godbolt.org/z/76M7rY7eE.  You're saying this an "other form" under 6.6p10?   I thought I saw some other places in the standard suggesting that it is supposed to be allowed; I will try to look them up.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is the puzzling part - why GCC accepts a compound literal as a constant expression in *some* initializers of static objects but not when that static object is an array for some reason! I guess it was an oversight.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That link has the compiler set to Clang. Clang’s behavior is not informative about GCC.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Or more specifically, why a compound literal in a conditional expression are accepted as a constant expression by GCC in some initializers but not in static arrays.

Comment: "Constant expression" is a defined term; see C17 6.6.  The language spec does not define or require implementations to recognize any kind of constant expression having union or aggregate type ("literal" != "constant").  It does explicitly permit implementations to accept forms of constant expression in addition to those described in the spec, but that does not make such recognition any less an extension than it otherwise would be.  I agree that GCC seems a bit inconsistent in this area, but that's among the risks you take when you rely on language extensions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: If an implementation defines a compound literal with constant expression initializers to be a constant expression, as permitted by 6.6 10, then using such a compound literal as an initializer for a static object does not violate the constraint in 6.7.9 4 that an initializer for a static object must be a constant expression, so no diagnostic is required. If an implementation does not define such a compound literal as a constant expression but accepts it as a non-constant-expression initializer for a static object, then the initializer violates 6.7.9 4 and must be diagnosed.

Comment: I do not disagree, @EricPostpischil.

Comment: For example, GCC is happy with `static Foo_t foo_static_arr2[] = { (Foo_t){ .a = UINT32_MAX } };` so it is specifically the compound literals as operands of the conditional operators that it doesn't like (except when it does like!).